# Paypal with SwipeStripe not redirecing

Tags: paypal, silverstripe, swipestripe

I have SwipeStripe working and would like to enable credit card payment through PayPal. I have installed the `paymant-paypal` module but am unable to get it to work.

After clicking `Proceed to Pay` on the checkout page I don't get redirected to the PayPal site (where I believe I should be able to choose from various credit cards). Instead, after few seconds I get redirected to my site with the payment `status=failure`.

In the database table `Payment_Error` the error message is:

> You are attempting to make a payment without the necessary credentials set

How do I fix this issue?

this is my payment.yml file:

```
Name: payment
After: 'framework/*','cms/*'
---
PaymentGateway:
  environment:
    'dev'

PaymentProcessor:
  supported_methods:
    dev:
      - 'Cheque'
      - 'PayPalExpress'
    live:
      - 'Cheque'
      - 'PayPalExpress'

PayPalGateway_Express: 
  live:
    authentication:
      username: 'merchant_api1.blabla.com'
      password: '8blablaPXJCVDW5B'
      signature: 'AblablablaYYRCpSSRl31Ai00Os2pnQ5XYyIbEdSPnSxbN7IL'
  dev:
    authentication:
      username: 'merchant_api1.blabla.com'
      password: '8blablaXJCVDW5B'
      signature: 'Ablablablad0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31Ai00Os2pnQ5XYyIbEdSPnSxbN7IL'
```

I am reading here (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/gs_PayPalAPIs/#call) that I should (while testing) also use statis AppID - but have no idea where to put it?

I created paypal sandbox seller and buyer account and am using seller's account username, password and signature in mysite/_config/payment.yml file (as described above). Should I be setting something on paypal site differently?

I did some research and I guess the problem lies in the way my module calls PayPal API - - if I try curl (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_calls/) with my credentials - I get ACK=Success, so I guess the problem is not in credentials but in the way module calls API - - so I am wondering if anyone has got this module to work or there were any modifications? I have a feeling that a call to PayPal API is a problem. If someone can provide any ideas, I would appreciate it a lot.

I am slowly getting some insight of where could be the problem. The API call from my module returns RestfulService_Response - - serialize($response) is this:

```
O:23:"RestfulService_Response":6:{s:12:" * simpleXML";N;s:17:" * cachedResponse";b:0;s:13:" * statusCode";i:500;s:20:" * statusDescription";s:21:"Internal Server Error";s:10:"
```

This means that something is not ok on PayPal server or more likely - I am missing some config settings. I've read somewhere that I should provide btest buyer info somewhere in config, but I don't know how to do that. If someone has a qlue how to do that, would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Have you configured the payment-provider in your YML files? As described here: https://github.com/frankmullenger/silverstripe-payment-paypal

Comment: I believe I have set up yml file correctly (according to instructions in your link). I also see in SS log file: $auth['USER'], $auth['PWD'], and $auth['SIGNATURE'] values (i put log calls in _private function callAPI($data) in PayPalGateway.php_ from this yml file. I now these should be sent to PayPal, but I am not sure if I need to set something up on PayPal accounts. Is there a way to check at PayPal if data get send to their server correctly. Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information what you tried… the error message is pretty clear, there seem to be missing credentials. So maybe post your YML file in the question too (replace the actual credentials with dummy-data).